# What is the correct way to store data in the DOM

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, dom

I have recently been using the title tag in various HTML elements to store data in JSON format in the DOM.

Is this a bad approach (I am assuming it is)? What is the correct way to accomplish this that works well with jQuery? By "works well" I mean

```
$("myButton").click(function (e) {
     var myData;
     eval("myData=" + $(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Works pretty well but again I am assuming there is a better way to do this no?

PS: BTW how does the title tag of HTML elements actually work? I cant seem to find where it actually ends up getting used?

PSS: Can I also get a jQuery based and Non jQuery response? (Sorry to be fussy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
eval("myData=" + $(this).attr("title"));
```

This is almost a legal reason to slap you! (j/k)

You should use your own namespace object to store data "globally". In that context, globally means only global in your application code and not using the `global object` (`window` in a browser).

```
var my_application = {};

$('myButton').click(function() {
  my_application.myData = $(this).attr('title');
});
```

This is a very basic strategy of course. In your particular case, you can also use jQuery's `.data()` method to attach data to a DOM node.

```
$('myButton').click(function() {
   $.data(this, 'myData', this.title);
});
```

Ref.: [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: lol.... Hold on... Isnt myData since it is declared above the eval local to the anonymous function in which it resides?

Comment: @MaximGershkovich: yes, but why would you use `eval()` at all then? You can just assign a value to the local variable.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have been more clear $(this).attr('title') = { someID: "", someProperty: "", anotherProperty: "" } . Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaximGershkovich: I'm confused. So the value of the `title` is an object or JSON string? If you want to parse a JSON you should use `JSON.parse()` over eval.. but I'm not sure if I understand the problem really.

Comment: wooo.... Its a JSON STRING.... Are you saying I can put a JSON object straight into the property? Running back to my IDE now to test....

Comment: @MaximGershkovich: Yes of course you can. JSON objects are just `string literals`. Anyway it's maybe not the best idea to hold that in the `.title` attribute which is visibible via tooltip / hover.

Answer (score 8):

In your example, I'd suggest doing the following which does not expose you to the security risks of 'eval':

```
myData = JSON.decode($(this).attr("title"));
```

In general it's a valid approach to holding non-secure data. You have a number of other options too:

- Use JQuery's .data() methods:

  myData = $this.data("foo");
- In HTML5 you now can use custom data attributes (Eg "") as an attribute on any element. http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
- You could use Local Storage if you know it is available. http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/
- You could use Backbone.js on top of Jquery to give you a more abstracted way of handling your data as Models. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Answer (score 4):

use jquery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to
>   attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from
>   circular references and therefore free
>   from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that
>   the data is removed when DOM elements
>   are removed via jQuery methods, and
>   when the user leaves the page. We can
>   set several distinct values for a
>   single element and retrieve them
>   later:

```
jQuery.data(document.body, 'foo', 52);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery world it is usually said to be a best practice to use the metadata plugin as it is an official jQuery plugin and also supports HTML5 data attributes. For more info you could look at this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata/metadata